# SWT Browser advanced functionality with WEBKIT

Tags: java, browser, webkit, swt, zooming

I am currently building an SWT application that must be easily portable and have a simple, fully functional web browser. I chose to use webkit mostly because it is already installed on osx, major linux distros and can be installed easily on windows by installing Safari.

I've added basic functionality to my browser, all of the things you can do explicitly with the browser class (status text, progress bar, ect), but I've run into trouble adding functionality that must communicate more directly with the rendering engine.

For example, I've been trying to add zoom functionality. There is a [snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet329.java) on the SWT page that shows how to do this with Mozilla as the rendering engine but it relies on the browser.getWebBrowser() function, which returns null with any engine except mozilla.

From the searching I've done, i've found a port of Webkit to SWT that is now defunct, and a bunch of examples of things I have already done. Is there any kind of nsIWebBrowser-like object for Webkit i have not been able to find? If not, I'm guessing my best bet is to either use mozilla, or write these functions myself using javascript and extending the [BrowserFunction class](http://dist.gumtree.codehaus.org/files/javadoc/eclipse/3.6/org/eclipse/swt/browser/BrowserFunction.html).

If i choose mozilla how easily would I be able to package the XLU runner with my final application so that a user doesn't have to install it separately? If I choose webkit is there any good documentation I have not been able to find about using javascript with the BrowserFunction class to implement this kind of functionality.

I also will eventually have to implement Find, Downloading, video playback, and undo/redo. What direction would you recommend I go in?

thank you for your help!

Comment: Break question into 2: for Webkit case and for mozilla case. Have you checked docs http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fbrowser%2FBrowser.html

Comment: Well, you asked more then 3 questions actually. For question add link to this question URL to help you and others to navigate and understand context / previous question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From the searching I've done, i've found a port of Webkit to SWT that
>   is now defunct, and a bunch of examples of things I have already done.
>   Is there any kind of nsIWebBrowser-like object for Webkit i have not
>   been able to find?

If you are looking for something exactly like nsIWebBrowser then there is **none**. But you may find this `org.eclipse.swt.internal.webkit.IWebView` somewhat similar.

> If not, I'm guessing my best bet is to either use mozilla, or write
>   these functions myself using javascript and extending the
>   BrowserFunction class.

The mozilla implementation has its root in ***The Original Code is Mozilla Communicator client code, which was released in 1998.***, whereas Webkit implementation was done by the SWT team. In my experience I have found working with XULRunner a bit difficult. The problem is normally due to SWT's dependence on a particular version of XULRunner. See [SWT FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php).

Extending the BrowserFunction could be a complicated, but you can try it.

> If i choose mozilla how easily would I be able to package the XLU
>   runner with my final application so that a user doesn't have to
>   install it separately?

Its easy just bundle the appropriate XULRunner and set right system properties before starting the application. See the [SWT FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php).

> If I choose webkit is there any good documentation I have not been
>   able to find about using javascript with the BrowserFunction class to
>   implement this kind of functionality.

Hmm. Not sure. You have to google it a bit further or wait for someone who knows about it.

> I also will eventually have to implement Find, Downloading, video
>   playback, and undo/redo. What direction would you recommend I go in?

Study `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Webkit` class and its supporting classes, like,  `org.eclipse.swt.browser.WebDownloadDelegate`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, after investigating the XULrunner further I was stunned to see that the latest version was the engine behind firefox 3! That must be over 10 years old, I'm definitely going with webkit. Unfortunately I have no idea how to invoke methods with the packages you mention on my browser object. I also haven't found documentation, only javadoc i found for [swt.internal](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/eclipse/swt/internal/package-index.html) doesn't have webkit as a sub-package. I'll take another look tomorrow but for now maybe you can tell me how to get the material to study?

Comment: Check this link http://www.modeliosoft.com/example/javadoc_SWT/org/eclipse/swt/internal/webkit/IWebView.html. The browser support in SWT is very platform dependent for example, on windows it is based on Microsoft COM technology. What SWT has done is to separate out basic browser functionality in an abstract class `WebBrowser` and as per target OS native browser wrappers are written. Its purely a digging deeper into the SWT code, but beware, the functionality written for one OS may not work on other !